# Sort a pandas dataframe series by month name

Tags: python, pandas, sorting, date, dataframe

I have a Series object that has:

```
    date   price
    dec      12
    may      15
    apr      13
    ..
```

**Problem statement:** I want to make it appear by month and compute the mean price for each month and present it with a sorted manner by month.

Desired Output:

```
 month mean_price
  Jan    XXX
  Feb    XXX
  Mar    XXX
```

I thought of making a list and passing it in a sort function:

```
months = ["Jan", "Feb", "Mar", "Apr", "May", "Jun", "Jul", "Aug", "Sep", "Oct", "Nov", "Dec"]
```

but the *sort_values* doesn't support that for series.

One big problem I have is that even though

`df = df.sort_values(by='date',ascending=True,inplace=True)` works
to the initial `df` but after I did a `groupby`, it didn't maintain the order coming out from the sorted `df`.

To conclude, I needed from the initial data frame these two columns. Sorted the datetime column and through a groupby using the month (dt.strftime('%B')) the sorting got messed up. Now I have to sort it by month name.

---

My code:

```
df # has 5 columns though I need the column 'date' and 'price'

df.sort_values(by='date',inplace=True) #at this part it is sorted according to date, great
total=(df.groupby(df['date'].dt.strftime('%B'))['price'].mean()) # Though now it is not as it was but instead the months appear alphabetically
```

Comment: Please consider accepting this [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/48043319/7758804). Even the author of the [accepted answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/48043339/7758804), stated it's better. Thanks

Answer (score 9, accepted):

*Thanks @Brad Solomon for offering a faster way to capitalize string!*

**Note 1** @Brad Solomon's answer using [`pd.categorical`](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.Categorical.html) should save your resources more than my answer. He showed how to assign order to your categorical data. You should not miss it :P

Alternatively, you can use.

```
df = pd.DataFrame([["dec", 12], ["jan", 40], ["mar", 11], ["aug", 21],
                  ["aug", 11], ["jan", 11], ["jan", 1]], 
                   columns=["Month", "Price"])
# Preprocessing: capitalize `jan`, `dec` to `Jan` and `Dec`
df["Month"] = df["Month"].str.capitalize()

# Now the dataset should look like
#   Month Price
#   -----------
#    Dec    XX
#    Jan    XX
#    Apr    XX

# make it a datetime so that we can sort it: 
# use %b because the data use the abbreviation of month
df["Month"] = pd.to_datetime(df.Month, format='%b', errors='coerce').dt.month
df = df.sort_values(by="Month")

total = (df.groupby(df['Month'])['Price'].mean())

# total 
Month
1     17.333333
3     11.000000
8     16.000000
12    12.000000
```

**Note 2**
`groupby` by default will sort group keys for you. Be aware to use the same key to sort and groupby in the `df = df.sort_values(by=SAME_KEY)` and `total = (df.groupby(df[SAME_KEY])['Price'].mean()).` Otherwise, one may gets unintended behavior. See [Groupby preserve order among groups? In which way?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48044542/groupby-preserve-order-among-groups-in-which-way) for more information.

**Note 3**
A more computationally efficient way is first compute mean and then do sorting on months. In this way, you only need to sort on 12 items rather than the whole `df`. It will reduce the computational cost if one don't need `df` to be sorted.

**Note 4** For people already have **`month` as index**, and wonder how to make it categorical, take a look at [pandas.`CategoricalIndex`](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.CategoricalIndex.html) @jezrael has a working example on making categorical index ordered in [Pandas series sort by month index](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/40816144/pandas-series-sort-by-month-index)

Answer (score 44):

You can use categorical data to enable proper sorting with [`pd.Categorical`](https://pandas.pydata.org/docs/reference/api/pandas.Categorical.html):

```
months = ["Jan", "Feb", "Mar", "Apr", "May", "Jun", 
          "Jul", "Aug", "Sep", "Oct", "Nov", "Dec"]
df['months'] = pd.Categorical(df['months'], categories=months, ordered=True)
df.sort_values(...)  # same as you have now; can use inplace=True
```

When you specify the categories, pandas remembers the order of specification as the default sort order.

Docs: Pandas categories > [sorting & order](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/user_guide/categorical.html#sorting-and-order).

Answer (score 16):

You should consider re-indexing it based on axis 0 (indexes)

```
new_order = ['January', 'February', 'March', 'April', 'May', 'June', 'July', 'August', 'September', 'October', 'November', 'December']

df1 = df.reindex(new_order, axis=0)
```

Answer (score 1):

I would use the `calender` module and `reindex`:

[`series.str.capitalize`](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.Series.str.capitalize.html) helps capitalizing the series , then we create a dictionary with the `calender` module and [`map`](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.Series.map.html) with the series to get month number.

Once we have the month number we can [`sort_values()`](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.Series.sort_values.html) and get the index. Then [`reindex`](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.reindex.html) .

```
import calendar
df.date=df.date.str.capitalize() #capitalizes the series
d={i:e for e,i in enumerate(calendar.month_abbr)} #creates a dictionary
#d={i[:3]:e for e,i in enumerate(calendar.month_name)} 
df.reindex(df.date.map(d).sort_values().index) #map + sort_values + reindex with index
```

---

```
  date  price
2  Apr     13
1  May     15
0  Dec     12
```

Answer (score 0):

use **Sort_Dataframeby_Month** function to sort month names in chronological order

Packages need to install.

```
$ pip install sorted-months-weekdays
$ pip install sort-dataframeby-monthorweek
```

example:

```
from sorted_months_weekdays import *

from sort_dataframeby_monthorweek import *

df = pd.DataFrame([['Jan',23],['Jan',16],['Dec',35],['Apr',79],['Mar',53],['Mar',12],['Feb',3]], columns=['Month','Sum'])
df
Out[11]: 
  Month  Sum
0   Jan   23
1   Jan   16
2   Dec   35
3   Apr   79
4   Mar   53
5   Mar   12
6   Feb    3
```

To sort dataframe by Month use below function

```
Sort_Dataframeby_Month(df=df,monthcolumnname='Month')
Out[14]: 
  Month  Sum
0   Jan   23
1   Jan   16
2   Feb    3
3   Mar   53
4   Mar   12
5   Apr   79
6   Dec   35
```

Answer (score 0):

You can add the numerical month value together with the name in the index (i.e "01 January"), do a sort then strip off the number:

```
total=(df.groupby(df['date'].dt.strftime('%m %B'))['price'].mean()).sort_index()
```

It may look sth like this:

```
01 January  xxx
02 February     yyy
03 March    zzz
04 April    ttt

 total.index = [ x.split()[1] for x in total.index ]

January xxx
February yyy
March zzz
April ttt
```