# Groupby preserve order among groups? In which way?

Tags: python, python-3.x, pandas

While answering a question [Sort a pandas's dataframe series by month name?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48042915/sort-a-series-by-month-name/48043339#48043339) we meet some weird behavior of `groupby`.

```
df = pd.DataFrame([["dec", 12], ["jan", 40], ["mar", 11], ["aug", 21], ["aug", 11], ["jan", 11], ["jan", 1]], columns=["Month", "Price"])
df["Month_dig"] = pd.to_datetime(df.Month, format='%b', errors='coerce').dt.month
df.sort_values(by="Month_dig", inplace=True)

# Now df looks like
    Month   Price   Month_dig
1   jan     40      1
5   jan     11      1
6   jan     1       1
2   mar     11      3
3   aug     21      8
4   aug     11      8
0   dec     12      12

total = (df.groupby(df['Month'])['Price'].mean())
print(total)
# output
Month
aug    16.000000
dec    12.000000
jan    17.333333
mar    11.000000
Name: Price, dtype: float64
```

It seems that in `total`, the data is sorted alphabetically. While the OP and I were expecting

```
Month
jan    17.333333
mar    11.000000
aug    16.000000
dec    12.000000
Name: Price, dtype: float64
```

What's the mechanism behind `groupby`? I know that it preserves order within each group from the documentation but **is there a rule for the order among groups**? It seems to me a pretty straightforward group order would be ["jan", "mar", "aug", "dec"] as the data in `df` is sorted in this way.

p.s. From ["aug", "dec", "jan", "mar"], it seems these group names are sorted alphabetically.
I am using Python 3.6 and pandas '0.20.3'

Comment: Forget about using a surrogate column for sorting, it's wasteful. Use a `Categorical` column instead. Brad's answer is spot on there.

Comment: @cᴏʟᴅsᴘᴇᴇᴅ That's so true. I updated my answer to point people to his great answer.

Answer (score 12, accepted):

[`pandas.DataFrame.groupby`](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.DataFrame.groupby.html) has a `sort` argument that defaults to `True`.  Try

```
total = (df.groupby(df['Month'], sort=False)['Price'].mean())
```