# Sorting date data in pandas Series

Tags: python, python-3.x, pandas, sorting

The data looks like this:

```
0        Thursday
1        Thursday
2        Thursday
3        Thursday
etc, etc
```

My code:

```
import pandas as pd
data_file = pd.read_csv('./data/Chicago-2016-Summary.csv')
days = data_file['day_of_week']

order = ["Monday","Tuesday","Wednesday", "Thursday", "Friday", "Saturday", "Sunday"]

sorted(days, key=lambda x: order.index(x[0]))
print(days)
```

**This results in error:**

> ValueError: 'T' is not in list

I tried to sort and get this error but I have no idea what this means.

I just want to sort the data Monday-Sunday so I can do some visualizations.  Any suggestions?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Sort a series by month name?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48042915/sort-a-series-by-month-name)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can use pandas' `Categorical` data type for this:

```
order = ["Monday","Tuesday","Wednesday", "Thursday", "Friday", "Saturday", "Sunday"] 
data_file['day_of_week'] = pd.Categorical(data_file['day_of_week'], categories=order, ordered=True)
data_file.sort_values(by='day_of_week', inplace=True)
```

In your example, be aware that when you specify

```
days = data_file['day_of_week']
```

you are creating a view to that column (Series) within your `data_file` frame.  You may want to use `days = data_file['day_of_week'].copy()`.  Or, just work within the DataFrame as is done above.

Comment: I can't do a frequency histogram of how many instances there are of each day in the data set?  I'm trying to visually see which days have the most activity.

Comment: I would still like my graph to go in day order Monday-Sunday, instead of ordered by count.  As it is now, it goes Monday, Tuesday, Friday, Thursday, Saturday, Sunday, Wednesday based on the value counts for each day.

Comment: `data_file['day_of_week'].value_counts().sort_index().plot.bar()`?