# Sort months from january to december of months column in dataframe df

Tags: pandas

This might be a duplicate question but a simple answer and direct answer may help many,

I have a dataframe df which has following columns :

```
       months  knowledgebank  inventory  advisory  activities
0    november            415        431       517         506
1      august            285        346       225         226
2   september            383        411       365         381
3        june            589        532       526         559
4         may            695        651       557         624
5    february            467        339       340         453
6     january            821        501       744         711
7    december            554        432       640         384
8        july            484        503       422         494
9       april            512        390       422         500
10      march            360        387       267         403
11     october            462        233       200         322
```

I want to sort the months column from january to december

as:

```
     months  knowledgebank  inventory  advisory  activities
0   january            821        501       744         711
1   february           467        339       340         453
.       .
.       .  
.       .
11   december
```

Comment: This [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/48043319/9081267) answers your question

Comment: The redirected answers were somewhat different to mine .......but thanks for the quick answer!!

Comment: Only difference is that you have to change `Jan` to `January`, `Feb` to `February` etc.

Comment: yeah mate, I got it then....thanks

Comment: If some one needs the direct answer as one our mate mentioned and deleted:     1)import calendar                                      
 2)d={i.lower():e for e,i in enumerate(calendar.month_name)}
3)df=df.reindex(df.months.map(d).sort_values().index)

Comment: @Codenewbie yes, added the answer to the link in the dupe. Hence deleted it from here.