# How to melt the pd.DataFrame to organize the data? (toy example included)

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe, pivot, melt

### Issue

- I am curious to know how to melt the `data_df` in the toy example provided below to the `desired_df`.

```py
import pandas as pd

data_df = pd.DataFrame(data = [['FR','Aug',100], ['FR','Sep',170], ['FR','Oct',250],
                               ['KR','Aug',9], ['KR','Sep',12],['KR','Oct',19],
                               ['US','Aug',360], ['US','Sep',500], ['US','Oct',700]],
                       columns = ['country','time','covid19'])
data_df
>>>   country   time    covid19 
   0    FR       Aug      100
   1    FR       Sep      170
   2    FR       Oct      250
   3    KR       Aug       9
   4    KR       Sep      12
   5    KR       Oct      19
   6    US       Aug      360
   7    US       Sep      500
   8    US       Oct      700
```

- My desired output `desired_df` is as follows, country names at `columns`, time at `index`, and number of Covid 19 patients in the dataframe as `values`.

```py
desired_df
>>>     FR  KR  US
 Aug    100 9   360
 Sep    170 12  500
 Oct    250 19  700
```

- I think `pd.melt` would help, but it does not create index and columns as I wanted.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try `pivot`:

```
data = data_df.pivot(index = 'time', columns = 'country')
print(data)
```

Which gives:

```
country      FR  KR   US
time                    
Aug         100   9  360
Oct         250  19  700
Sep         170  12  500
```

The indices are in alphabetical order.  Reorder them as you like.  For ordering them calendrically, I'd suggest Brad Solomon's answer to [Sort a pandas's dataframe series by month name?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48042915/sort-a-pandass-dataframe-series-by-month-name), which uses the `pd.Categorical`.