# Pivot table with months sorted chronologically on Python

Tags: python, pandas, datetime, pivot

I am trying to create a pivot table with the months sorted chronologically on Python. But the months are sorted alphabetically. The data is drawn from a time series.

The code:

```
import numpy as np
import pandas as pd
import datetime as dt
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import seaborn as sns
 
df_air = pd.read_csv('https://raw.githubusercontent.com/AileenNielsen/TimeSeriesAnalysisWithPython/master/data/AirPassengers.csv',
         parse_dates=['Month'], date_parser=lambda x: pd.to_datetime(x, format='%Y-%m', errors = 'coerce'))

df_air.reset_index(inplace=True)

df_air['year'] = [d.year for d in df_air.Month]
df_air['month'] = [d.strftime('%b') for d in df_air.Month]

df_air_pivot_table = df_air.pivot(index="year", columns="month", values="#Passengers")
df_air_pivot_table.head(12)
```

What's wrong?

### AirPassengers.csv

- Incase the repo with the data goes away

```
Month,#Passengers
1949-01,112
1949-02,118
1949-03,132
1949-04,129
1949-05,121
1949-06,135
1949-07,148
1949-08,148
1949-09,136
1949-10,119
1949-11,104
1949-12,118
1950-01,115
1950-02,126
1950-03,141
1950-04,135
1950-05,125
1950-06,149
1950-07,170
1950-08,170
1950-09,158
1950-10,133
1950-11,114
1950-12,140
1951-01,145
1951-02,150
1951-03,178
1951-04,163
1951-05,172
1951-06,178
1951-07,199
1951-08,199
1951-09,184
1951-10,162
1951-11,146
1951-12,166
1952-01,171
1952-02,180
1952-03,193
1952-04,181
1952-05,183
1952-06,218
1952-07,230
1952-08,242
1952-09,209
1952-10,191
1952-11,172
1952-12,194
1953-01,196
1953-02,196
1953-03,236
1953-04,235
1953-05,229
1953-06,243
1953-07,264
1953-08,272
1953-09,237
1953-10,211
1953-11,180
1953-12,201
1954-01,204
1954-02,188
1954-03,235
1954-04,227
1954-05,234
1954-06,264
1954-07,302
1954-08,293
1954-09,259
1954-10,229
1954-11,203
1954-12,229
1955-01,242
1955-02,233
1955-03,267
1955-04,269
1955-05,270
1955-06,315
1955-07,364
1955-08,347
1955-09,312
1955-10,274
1955-11,237
1955-12,278
1956-01,284
1956-02,277
1956-03,317
1956-04,313
1956-05,318
1956-06,374
1956-07,413
1956-08,405
1956-09,355
1956-10,306
1956-11,271
1956-12,306
1957-01,315
1957-02,301
1957-03,356
1957-04,348
1957-05,355
1957-06,422
1957-07,465
1957-08,467
1957-09,404
1957-10,347
1957-11,305
1957-12,336
1958-01,340
1958-02,318
1958-03,362
1958-04,348
1958-05,363
1958-06,435
1958-07,491
1958-08,505
1958-09,404
1958-10,359
1958-11,310
1958-12,337
1959-01,360
1959-02,342
1959-03,406
1959-04,396
1959-05,420
1959-06,472
1959-07,548
1959-08,559
1959-09,463
1959-10,407
1959-11,362
1959-12,405
1960-01,417
1960-02,391
1960-03,419
1960-04,461
1960-05,472
1960-06,535
1960-07,622
1960-08,606
1960-09,508
1960-10,461
1960-11,390
1960-12,432
```

Comment: This [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/48043319/7758804) from the duplicate. Do this to the `'month'` column before pivoting.

Comment: Also, it should be `df_air['year'] = df_air.Month.dt.year` and `df_air['month'] = df_air.Month.dt.strftime('%b')`, not the list comprehensions you're using. `df_air.reset_index(inplace=True)` shouldn't be needed.

Comment: See [code and plot](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Xqqrl.png)

Comment: One thing to note in the plot, is the colors are reused because there aren't enough values in that palette. `ax = dp.plot(cmap="viridis")` for example.