# Combine a row with column in dataFrame and show the corresponding values

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe, numpy

So I want to show this data in just two columns. For example, I want to turn this data

```
  Year  Jan     Feb      Mar    Apr      May    Jun 
  1997  3.45    2.15    1.89    2.03    2.25    2.20
  1998  2.09    2.23    2.24    2.43    2.14    2.17
  1999  1.85    1.77    1.79    2.15    2.26    2.30
  2000  2.42    2.66    2.79    3.04    3.59    4.29
```

into this

```
  Date        Price
Jan-1977       3.45
Feb-1977       2.15
Mar-1977       1.89
Apr-1977       2.03
....
Jan-2000       2.42
Feb-2000       2.66
```

So far, I have read about how to combine two columns into another dataframe using `.apply()` `.agg()`, but no info how to combine them as I showed above.

```
import pandas as pd

df = pd.read_csv('matrix-A.csv', index_col =0 )

matrix_b = ({})
new = pd.DataFrame(matrix_b)

new["Date"] = df['Year'].astype(float) + "-" + df["Dec"]
print(new)
```

I have tried this way, but it of course does not work. I have also tried using `pd.Series()` but no success

I want to ask whether there is any site where I can learn how to do this, or does anybody know correct way to solve this?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Another possible solution, which is based on [`pandas.DataFrame.stack`](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.stack.html):

```
out = df.set_index('Year').stack()
out.index = ['{}_{}'.format(j, i) for i, j in out.index]
out = out.reset_index()
out.columns = ['Date', 'Value']
```

Output:

```
        Date  Value
0   Jan_1997   3.45
1   Feb_1997   2.15
2   Mar_1997   1.89
3   Apr_1997   2.03
4   May_1997   2.25
....
19  Feb_2000   2.66
20  Mar_2000   2.79
21  Apr_2000   3.04
22  May_2000   3.59
23  Jun_2000   4.29
```

Answer (score 2):

You can use [`pandas.DataFrame.melt`](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.melt.html) :

```
out = (
        df
          .melt(id_vars="Year", var_name="Month", value_name="Price")
          .assign(month_num= lambda x: pd.to_datetime(x["Month"] , format="%b").dt.month)
          .sort_values(by=["Year", "month_num"])
          .assign(Date= lambda x: x.pop("Month") + "-" + x.pop("Year").astype(str))
          .loc[:, ["Date", "Price"]]
      )
```

##### # Output :

```
print(out)
    ​
        Date  Price
0   Jan-1997   3.45
4   Feb-1997   2.15
8   Mar-1997   1.89
12  Apr-1997   2.03
16  May-1997   2.25
..       ...    ...
7   Feb-2000   2.66
11  Mar-2000   2.79
15  Apr-2000   3.04
19  May-2000   3.59
23  Jun-2000   4.29

[24 rows x 2 columns]
```

Answer (score 2):

You can first convert it to long-form using `melt`. Then, create a new column for `Date` by combining two columns.

```
long_df = pd.melt(df, id_vars=['Year'], var_name='Month', value_name="Price")
long_df['Date'] = long_df['Month'] + "-" + long_df['Year'].astype('str')
long_df[['Date', 'Price']]
```

If you want to sort your date column, [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48042915/sort-a-pandas-dataframe-series-by-month-name) is a good resource. Follow those instructions after `melt`ing and before creating the `Date` column.